# How do I get value from Table B if Value in Table A is not null

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I am new to SQL queries but if I were writing this in the programming language I have used for years it would look something like this:

```
SELECT patfile.Chart_Number
    ,patfile.employer AS e_name
FROM patfile;

IF (
        patfile.employer = ''
        ,(
            SELECT addfile.NAME AS e_name
            FROM addfile
            WHERE patfile.employer = addfile.code
            )
        ,''
        ) ELSE patfile.employer AS e_name endif
```

Final Result should look like this:

```
Patient     Employer
RUSTY
PAM         AT&T
DON         7 ELEVEN
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Sample input / source data?

Comment: Sorry but the "Should Look Like This" did not come out formatted the same as I posted in the question. Rusty would come out with no employer while Pam would show AT&T as employer and Don would show 7 Eleven as employer.

Comment: Use a [left outer join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Comment: As i am understanding you you are asking for case statement

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT patfile.Chart_Number
    ,  CASE WHEN patfile.employer = ''
         THEN (
            SELECT addfile.NAME AS e_name
            FROM addfile
            WHERE patfile.employer = addfile.code
            )
         ELSE patfile.employer END AS e_name
FROM patfile
```

Answer (score 1):

The main thing is to `LEFT JOIN` to the additional table.

Then you have to choose the second name if the first is null (or blank, depending on your data.) I don't know the Advantage database, but different dialects of SQL support this in different ways.

If the missing value is null, not blank, then MySQL and SQLServer have `IFNULL`. Your SQL would look something like this (not tested):

```
SELECT patfile.Chart_Number, IFNULL(patfile.employer, addfile.name) AS e_name
FROM patfile
LEFT JOIN addfile ON patfile.employer = addfile.code
```

Oracle has `NVL` which works the same way, but it is Oracle-only. It's preferable to use `COALESCE` which is part of the ANSI standard and supported by more databases.

Some databases have an IF function. That may also be in the ANSI standard, I'm not sure. You can use that to test for a value that's not NULL, like ''.

```
SELECT patfile.Chart_Number, IF(patfile.employer = '', patfile.employer, addfile.name) AS e_name
FROM patfile
LEFT JOIN addfile ON patfile.employer = addfile.code
```

So look in your database docs for a function like `IF`, `ISNULL`, or `COALESCE`.

Comment: Thank You Bampfer. Using the left join, I got close to what I was looking for. I created a statement as follows:

Comment: Thank You Bampfer. Using the left join, I got close to what I was looking for. I created a statement as follows:

SELECT patfile.chart_number
     , addfile.name as e_name

FROM
        patfile  LEFT JOIN  addfile
  ON   patfile.employer    =    addfile.code

The only thing I need to do now is add my where statements so that I limit the amount of names to those for a certain date, and it should give me what I need.